# How to get "qualification_type_id" when using Boto API

Tags: python, boto, mechanicalturk

It seems that the following code should return a `qual` which contain a `qualification_type_id` attribute. But it does not when I use `dir(qual)` to check. Since lots of functions in Boto require `qualification_type_id` as a parameter. I just want to know how to get the `qualification_type_id`.

```
qualification = Qualifications()
qual = mtc.create_qualification_type(name = 'q', description='qualification', status = 'Active')
print dir(qual)
```

Comment: Can you format your code as code?  (Hint use the braces {} button at the top of the edit box.  Also, do you get a traceback? or just not the expected results?

Comment: I do not get expected results. As it shows here (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_QualificationTypeDataStructureArticle.html ) A Qualification type is given a Qualification type ID when you call the CreateQualificationType operation operation, and it retains that ID forever.

Answer (score 0):

```
qualification = Qualifications()
```

qual = mtc.create_qualification_type(name = 'q', description='qualification', status = 'Active')
print dir(qual)